# NI Labview FPGA: ERROR:Portability:3 - Xilinx Application has run out of memory

Tags: fpga, xilinx, labview

I am using NI Labview FPGA to compile and synthesise a design onto the FPGA and have encountered the following error:

```
LabVIEW FPGA:  The compilation failed due to a Xilinx error.

Details:
ERROR:Portability:3 - This Xilinx application has run out of memory or has encountered a memory conflict.  Current memory usage is 4025524 kb.  You can try increasing your system's physical or virtual memory.  If you are using a Win32 system, you can increase your application memory from 2GB to 3GB using the /3G switch in your boot.ini file. For more information on this, please refer to Xilinx Answer Record #14932. For technical support on this issue, please visit http://www.xilinx.com/support. 

Process "Synthesize - XST" failed
INFO:TclTasksC:1850 - process run : Synthesize - XST is done.


Compilation Time
---------------------------
Date submitted: 17/01/2017 15:41
Date results were retrieved: 17/01/2017 17:01
Time waiting in queue: 00:11
Time compiling: 01:19:20
- Generate Xilinx IP: 00:00
- Estimate Resources - PlanAhead: 03:04
- Synthesize - XST: 01:14:54
```

Does this mean the cloud compile server is running out of memory? Or is my local computer running out of memory?

I assume it is the local computer. How might I get around this such that I can compile my design?

Comment: It is whichever computer is currently running the Xilinx synthesis software that is running out of memory for the application process. You need to increase the amount of memory that is allocated to that process (for example, by increasing your virtual memory size, adding more RAM, or changing the settings to allow more memory to be allocated for the Xilinx process).

Comment: Looks like an old error given on 32-bit Windows machines, which divide the 4GB space into two 2GB space - if this is the case, the only way is to use the 3G switch otherwise get a 64-bit OS. What are your machine's specs.?

Comment: It's a 32 bit windows 7 computer with 2GB of Ram, it's so low spec because it is built into the Chassis of the NI device we use.

Comment: As such is a bit out of date. Do you think it could work on this or using an external 64 bit machine with more ram will be the only solution?

Comment: More ram could help but you would be best off to use the 3GB switch as suggested by fpga_magik more details here http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/14932.html

Also what could help is configuring your compilation to be offloaded to the cloud to be compiled on the NI cloud servers which should resolve the issue see the following
http://www.ni.com/white-paper/11573/en/

Comment: I have attempted to use the 3GB switch, I did this by running the command `bcdedit /set IncreaseUserVa 3072` in a cmd prompt window using run as admin, I then restarted the computer before re-attempting the compilation.  I believe I am also using the NI cloud compile server as when I compile my design I get the following window pop up: [Compilation window](http://imgur.com/TUIeQxQ) which I believe means it is indeed using the cloud compile server. I am unsure why this issue is occurring if I am using the cloud compile server as all the heavy computational work should be done on the server.

Comment: could it be that there is some limit on the ram on the cloud compile server? As I understand it, the synthesis process is not parallelisable and so has to run on 1 core. It's odd that it's reporting it ran out of memory at 4GB when the local computer I'm using only has 2GB of ram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with an NI engineer it appears that my design was just too large for the FPGA and the cloud compile server is only designed to support compilation of designs which could actually fit on their FPGAs, 4GB of Ram appears to be all you should need to compile a design onto any NI provdided FPGA.