# NI myRIO 1900 FPGA Compilation in labVIEW

Tags: labview

i am using the embedded system called NI myRIO 1900, whene i try to compile the FPGA in labview using my PC i get a message that " the memory is full" and another message that the free memory is 137 Mbits given that the internal memory of myRIO 1900 is 200 Mbits, i don't know what's wrong, i've tried several times to compile the program but it didn't works, please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

**1) Your PC is running out of memory due to your LabVIEW program**

see this post here at the [NI docs](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000P9mtSAC&l=de-DE). This can happen due to large LabVIEW programs but is highly unlikely in your case. But it is good to know that LabVIEW stores variables contiguously in memory (RAM), so if you a lot of programs running, a small RAM, and a large program, LabVIEW might encounter the problem that there simply is not a large-enough block of RAM available to store a certain variable or result. (Solution: increase the [*virtual memory*](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000PAaPSAW&l=de-DE)... and close all other programs)

**2) Your PC is running out of memory while compiling**

Picking up the last argument from the previous option: you might just have too much windows open and running at an old machine. FPGA compiling consumes quite an amount of memory (and time) as it needs to generate the whole structure of the FPGA-wiring.
(Solution: close all other programs or increase the [*virtual memory*](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000PAaPSAW&l=de-DE) so that windows can shift all other open programs to the virtual memory aka. swap)

**3) Your program is simply too large for the FPGA**

Your error will look something like this

> This Xilinx application has run out of memory or has encountered a
>   memory conflict.

Check out this [post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41704533/ni-labview-fpga-errorportability3-xilinx-application-has-run-out-of-memory). Well, the easy solution is to decrease the size of your program by choosing smaller data types for your calculations. Note that LabVIEW tries to make programing easy and automatically increases the size of your variables e.g. if you multiply them. This can be costly at integer-level but is really painful if you work with fix-points. Click on the blocks (add, multiply etc.) and tell them manually that you want to have a certain type as output. Be sure, that your input will actually never cause the output to overflow...